# Should I load my model pkl object every time when I predict?

Tags: python, pickle

I am predicting the data in real time , when I hit the url it should predict but I should not load my model again and again . Can someone help to optimize the code ?
Can I load globally or how can I persist my model object session while prediction ?

```
@app.route("/predict",methods = ['GET'])
def predictData():
    try:
        message = request.args.get('message', default = '')
        message = message.translate(str.maketrans(string.punctuation, ' '*len(string.punctuation)))

        text_clf_nb_fit = joblib.load('UpdatedAmtAlertClassifierModel.pkl')

        result = text_clf_nb_fit.predict([message])
```

Thanks in advance .

Comment: It has nothing to do with ML as such, a simple strategy is to load it when the server starts once and keep it in memory, as simple as that.

Comment: In my case I am calling update model  asynchronously **@app.route("/update",methods = ['GET']) ** where I am saving the ** joblib.dump(clf_update,'UpdatedAmtAlertClassifierModel.pkl') ** how can I reload my model while prediction ??